# SSIS Slow Changing Dimension

Tags: sql, ssis

When using the SSIS function Slow Changing Dimension, how could I add a column to the destination table that will tell me when my records are current or not?

I am moving data from my Customer table into my DimCustomer Table using the Slow Changing Dimension Function in SSIS. However, I would like to add a column to my DimCustomer name 'IsCurrent' that will tell me when my values are current or not. But I don't know how to do that.

Basically what I have in mind how to write the Statement: `WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'`

Need your help figuring out how to track my Current and Not Current values.

Below is my Customer Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
CustomerNumber Char(8) PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName nvarchar(50) Not NULL,
MiddleName nvarchar(1) Null,
LastName nvarchar(50) Not Null,
EmailAddress nvarchar(320) Not Null,
Phone  varchar(25) Not Null,
Country nvarchar(20) Not Null,
City nvarchar(20) Not Null,
StateProvince nvarchar(10) Not Null,
Addressline1 nvarchar (250) Not Null,
Addressline2 nvarchar (250) Null
)
```

Below is my DimCustomer table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DimCustomers (
CustomerKey Int Identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
CustomerNumber Char(8) Not Null,
FirstName nvarchar(50) Not NULL,
MiddleName nvarchar(1) Null,
LastName nvarchar(50) Not Null,
EmailAddress nvarchar(320) Not Null,
Phone  varchar(25) Not Null,
Country nvarchar(20) Not Null,
City nvarchar(20) Not Null,
StateProvince nvarchar(10) Not Null,
Addressline1 nvarchar (250) Not Null,
Addressline2 nvarchar (250) Null,
StartDate Datetime Null,
EndDate Datetime Null,
IsInerred Bit Default(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store it, unless you have to.

Instead, use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE
    dbo.DimCustomers
ADD
    IsCurrent AS (CASE WHEN EndDate IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END);
```

If you absolutely must store the value, then from an SSIS perspective you will need to have an Execute SQL Task after the Data Flow has completed. There, you will need to craft the appropriate query to recompute the IsCurrent value.